# Visual Basic Editing text config file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I need help on making a program that will take an existing variable storing an IP and change the existing one in a config.ini file next to Server=.
This is what the config file looks like.
Any help will be appreciated :)

```
[Configuration]
Server=192.168.0.150
WebHost=auto
Nickname=Ryan
[Dynamic]
HackWarningShown=True
ServerWarningShown=True
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself to do this first? That's a simple INI file, and you should be able to search here or Google for how to use an INI file from VB.net to at least make an effort. A quick search here, for instance, on `[vb.net] INI file` turned up [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16755029).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read/Write "INI" file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755029/read-write-ini-file)